# "You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory" error with compass project

Tags: sass, compass-sass, expressionengine

I've installed Zurb Foundation sass into an expressionengine project but i'm getting this when saving the app.scss file:

> Compass was unable to compile one or more files in the project:
>
> You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory.

All my paths are correct as they are the same as in another project that works fine.

Any idea what triggers that error so i can track down the issue?

Comment: I'm an idiot, in config.rb, the filepaths for css_dir, sass_dir etc etc need to be relative to the folder config.rb lives in.
I hadn't set them properly. What a fool!

Comment: This helped me, for the record.

Comment: Well I am having the same problem but don't know how to get out of it ?? please if u can

Comment: This helped a lot. Thanks for asking the question.

Comment: I was getting this error, but my problem was that I had Sass files in my CSS directory. (Or maybe I had CSS files in my Sass directory... can't remember...)

Comment: I don't know why this was closed, as it definitely not too localised and can turn up as a problem all the time for people new to compass
Anyway same problem, and i've posted an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419011/compass-you-must-compile-individual-stylesheets-from-the-project-directory/20010411#20010411

Comment: I had the same problem using the 'Scout' software (on OS X). The configuration I had used to work. I simply removed the project and added it again. Problem solved.